# Facebook Pages - How to get Access Token permissions - "perms" for a user on graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

Since Facebook added **Page Admin roles** on pages (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/), when getting the tokens via graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXX, it lists:

*"perms": [

```
        "ADMINISTER",
        "EDIT_PROFILE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MODERATE_CONTENT",
        "CREATE_ADS",
        "BASIC_ADMIN"

     ]*
```

How do we know if these have changed after getting a page access token - so for example: if a user loses their administrator role after I get the token, how do we check for that?

Answer (score 3):

I believe your best bet is polling.  If you're in a position where you need to know permissions, GET `me/accounts` again to see what the permissions are.

This tends to be the approach that I use - in my app, I rebuild relationships between tokens and accounts once per day.

Your other option is catching errors - if `myusersapp/insights` fails, you assume that they've lost permissions and update the relationship.  The problem that you'll face here is that insights go down every now and again, and you won't be able to detect permissions to new pages this way.

Comment: Is there no way to know this without also storing the user access token?  What if you only have a page access token?